# How to link multiple GUIs in netbeans

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans

I am new to this GUI stuff on NetBeans, so could someone please explain how to link multiple GUIs into one? This I should mention is in a java format.

Comment: Could you be a bit more detailed about what you mean by "linking multiple GUIs into one?"   What specific task are you face with?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open another gui from a specific gui, you should give an event to a button.

For example, if you want to open anothergui from maingui, you can create an event for a button which says anothergui is new anothergui, then you can set visibility true for anothergui.